# NEW INTENT causa: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, recyclerview

estoy atrapado en el siguiente error y acudo a los expertos porque ando loco con esto. Les explico...

Estaba trabajando con RealTime Basedata de Firebase y mi Adapter (Recyclerview) trabajaba perfecto (voy anexar ese codigo para que lo vean tambien). El detalle es que con RealTime Basedata de Firebase no podia filtrar bien los datos, ya seben no se puede hacer que los datos esten de forma descendiente y muchas consultas que no se pueden hacer bien al filtrar, asi que decidi cambiar al Cloud Firebase, pense que me iba a funciona el mismo codigo, pero no fue asi, ya que tuve que implementar la libreria de Firebase UI, para poder utilizar recyclerview con Cloud Firebase, esto viendo un tuto, que explican y funciona, el detalle es que el tuto solo muestras traer el listado, pero yo nenecito quu ese lostado al hacer click vaya a otra actividad, y alli esta el detalle, al implementar el new intent, y correr la app, al darle click me salta el rror ladilla de java.lang.NullPointerException jejeje. Estoy seguro que es por culpa del contexto, ya que no se en el nuevo codigo como implementarlo, de hecho pienso que esta bien, pero nada, les dejo ambos codigo, el que funciona con real time y el nuevo que me carga loco, espero que me puedas ayudar, de antemano Gracias.

------------- Error --------------

```
06-14 11:02:22.826 4102-4102/com.aaadesigner.fansvsfans E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.aaadesigner.fansvsfans, PID: 4102
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.aaadesigner.fansvsfans.RecyclerViewMasvotados$1.onClick(RecyclerViewMasvotados.java:51)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

-------------Codigo Viejo donde funcionaba perfecto con Real Time Base Data-------

```
public class RecyclerViewActivos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewActivos.MyViewHolder>  {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<activos> mData;
    private RequestOptions options;


    public RecyclerViewActivos(Context mContext, List<activos> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
        this.options = new RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.fondopersonajes)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC);
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listadoactivos,parent,false);
        final MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);

         viewHolder.view_contenedor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Campeonatos.class);
                intent.putExtra("nombre1", mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getNombre1());
                intent.putExtra("titulo", mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getTitulo());
                intent.putExtra("imagen1", mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getImagen1());                  

             mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.titulo.setText(mData.get(position).getTitulo());
        holder.creador.setText(mData.get(position).getCreador());
        holder.votostotales.setText(String.valueOf(mData.get(position).getVotostotales()));
        Glide.with(mContext).load(mData.get(position).getImagen1()).apply(options).into(holder.imagenprincipal);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        TextView votostotales, titulo, creador;
        LinearLayout view_contenedor;
        CircleImageView imagenprincipal;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            titulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
            imagenprincipal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagenprincipal);

            view_contenedor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contenedor);

        }
    }


}
```

------------ Codigo Nuevo Cloud Firebase con PROBLEMA Null Point Exception-------------------

```
public class RecyclerViewMasvotados extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<masvotados, RecyclerViewMasvotados.ViewHolder>{

    private static Context context;
    private RequestOptions options;
    private FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<masvotados, ViewHolder> mData;


    /**
     * Create a new RecyclerView adapter that listens to a Firestore Query.  See {@link
     * FirestoreRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
     *
     * @param options
     */
    RecyclerViewMasvotados(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<masvotados> options) {
        super(options);
        this.options = new RequestOptions()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.fondopersonajes)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC);

    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup viewGroup, final int viewType) {

        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listadomasvotados, viewGroup, false);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        viewHolder.view_contenedor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(viewGroup.getContext(), Campeonatos.class);
                intent.putExtra("nombre1", mData.getItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getNombre1());
                intent.putExtra("titulo", mData.getItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getTitulo());
                intent.putExtra("imagen1", mData.getItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getImagen1());
                

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull masvotados model) {


        holder.titulo.setText(model.getTitulo());
        holder.creador.setText(model.getCreador());
        holder.votostotales.setText(String.valueOf(model.getVotostotales()));

        Glide.with(context).load(model.getImagen1()).apply(options).into(holder.imagenprincipal);

    }


    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView votostotales, titulo, creador;
        LinearLayout view_contenedor;
        CircleImageView imagenprincipal;

        ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            context = itemView.getContext();
            titulo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
            imagenprincipal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagenprincipal);

            view_contenedor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contenedor);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Como dato extras, los cambios mas notorios del codigo nuevo por implementar la libreria de Firebase UI son:

1. tuve que extender el Recyclervire a; extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter
2. en el codigo viejo usaba una lista, aca no se utiliza.
3. Hay un metodo nuevo: FirestoreRecyclerOptions options que en el viejo no se utilizaba, se usaba algo parecido, eso seria los cambios del codigo como tal.

Les repito que el codigo funciona perfecto, hasta que le implemento el New Intent para abrir la nueva actividad, con los Extraput que necesito., el problema casi seguro es con el Context, pero de verdad que no se que pensar, espero pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Leyendo tu pregunta me parece que te estás liando demasiado conque si RealTime Database que si Firestore. Si hubieras trabajado en base a modelos de datos, lo único que cambiaría sería la forma en que te conectarías (porque eso es diferente) pero no los datos. Por poner un ejemplo, una `Persona` es una `Persona`, sea en RealTime Database, sea en Firestore, pues con un modelo, una vez obtenidos los datos, de donde sea, llenas el modelo con los datos y todo sigue normal. Cambiar de plataforma de almacenamiento no tendría por qué afectar lo demás, por tanto, creo que el problema fundamental ...

Comment: ... está ahí, en una concepción errónea sobre cómo funcionan las cosas. Si quieres evitar esos dolores de cabeza y escribir código fácil de portar y de mantener, detente un poco a analizar el modelo de datos y trabaja usando clases. Otra cosa que da pánico cuando trabajas con Firebase es que no organices bien los datos, por ejemplo, si para obtener una lista de personas de una empresa lees todos los documentos de personas te puede llegar una factura de varios miles de dólares al mes, porque Firebase organiza los datos de modo distinto a las bases de datos, entonces en muchos casos ...

Comment: ... hay que desnormalizar los datos, y aceptar que, en algunas ocasiones es mejor que algunos datos sean redundantes. El tema está más o menos explicado en la documentación de Firebase y sería bueno que analices un poco también eso para decidir la mejor manera de organizar tus datos si tienes que hacer búsquedas basadas en ciertos criterios.

Comment: Cual es la linea 51 de RecyclerViewMasvotados ? @aAaDesigner

Comment: Hola jorge es: intent.putExtra("nombre1", mData.getItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getNombre1()).    creo que estoy usando mal el putextra

Comment: Hola cedano, vale yo pensaba igual que tú, dije bueno simplemente cambio y me conecto a la otra base de datos y listo, pero resulta que no fue así, la manera de usar recyclerview con cloud es usando la librería de firebase UI,  e implemento todo, de repente este equivocado, pero con recyclerview que tenía no puede realizar la implementqcion. Lo otro es que al llamar a cloud debes de utilizar según la misma información de firebase firebaserecycleoptions.

Answer (score 0):

No es del todo correcto tratar de obtener la posiciòn dentro de onCreateViewHolder() , el problema es que si se elimina un elemento la posiciòn ya no se obtendrà ya que el valor serà -1, debido a esto tienes que realizar la siguiente validaciòn:

```
viewHolder.view_contenedor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

         int posicion = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

         if (posicion != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(viewGroup.getContext(), Campeonatos.class);
            intent.putExtra("nombre1", mData.getItem(posicion).getNombre1());
            intent.putExtra("titulo", mData.getItem(posicion).getTitulo());
            intent.putExtra("imagen1", mData.getItem(posicion).getImagen1());
            
            context.startActivity(intent);

         }

        }
    });
```

Revisa la documentaciòn:

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder